# Can I use __builtin_*_overflow as += or *=?

Tags: c, gcc

Is it legal to use a single variable for both source and destination of GCC's `__builtin_*_overflow` functions?

For example, given

```
int a, b;
```

I would like to write a checked `a += b` as

```
__builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &a)
```

Is this safe?

Comment: Why not? The parameters are passed by value.

Comment: Is `__builtin_*_overflow()` a function or a macro?

Comment: @EOF Looks like a function: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html So I don't see any problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Given that at least some of the function in that family seem to be doing type-magic, I'd say they are macros.

Comment: @EOF Well, I am reading the first line *The following built-in **functions**...*

Comment: @EugeneSh. Even the C-standard allows *functions* to be implemented as macros in some cases. How would `__builtin_*_overflow_p()` on the page you linked be implemented as a true function?

Comment: @EOF I don't think C standard would allow a function to be implemented as macro in case it will make the answer to the topic negative. I might be wrong, as I haven't seen that in the standard. But It would be the case if I've written it :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There's a sizable discussion about this in C11 draft standard n1570, `7.1.4 Use of library functions`, including this gem: *Such macros might not contain the sequence points that the corresponding function calls do.*

Comment: @EOF Nice finding and a bit frustrating. But this footnote is preceeded by "*Any invocation of a library function that is implemented as a macro shall expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once,*". Though the timing of the evaluation is not specified. So yes, theoretically it could first evaluate `&a`, clobber it, and then evaluate `a`... If I am not missing something.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Given that the *argument* is only evaluated once, the following sequence should be conforming: 1. Make a copy of `b`. 2. Make a copy of `&a` (the third argument) 3. Write the value of the copy of `b` to the address in the copy of the third argument (`== &a`). 3. Make a copy of `a`... And now things have gone wrong., since the subsequent copy of `a` will receive the value of the copy of `b` instead.

Comment: @EOF that's what I am saying in the second part. But wouldn't it make such a use of *any* library functions unsafe? Unless the safety is explicitly specified (which is not the case for most of them).

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It might. Though there are not too many function that take both a `T` and a `T*` as arguments, which would be required for this. Other than that, I'd say this could be a nice `language-lawyer` question.

Comment: @EugeneSh.and @EOF, I think I can take the use of the word "function" to imply that it must behave *as-if* `a` and `b` are captured by value before `&a` is used, making the answer "yes".  If you write an answer to that effect, I'll certainly accept.  The comment exchange has certainly improved my understanding (I have to admit I was worrying unnecessarily about pointer aliasing rules, despite there being only one pointer argument).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's sane to assume, that `__builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &a)` will work as `a += b`.

Note, that it may be as well invoked with constants:

```
__builtin_add_overflow(10, 5, &a)
```

Normally, GCC will treat it as intrinsic function, which means that its call is replaced internally by compiler with generated code. It's not treated as normal function (in the C sense), since there is no header file with its declaration. Hence, it's neither a inline function nor function-like macro.

[6.54 Built-in Functions to Perform Arithmetic with Overflow Checking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)

> The compiler will attempt to use hardware instructions to implement
>   these built-in functions where possible, like conditional jump on
>   overflow after addition, conditional jump on carry etc.

Here is an example (the better one is provided in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704568/can-i-use-builtin-overflow-as-or/41705791#comment70607394_41705791) below):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;

    __builtin_add_overflow(a, b, &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

which translates on GCC 6.3.0 with -O0 into (see [godbolt.org/g/UJqenc](https://godbolt.org/g/UJqenc)):

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 10      ; place a and b on stack
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]     ; copy a and b into GP registers
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    add     eax, edx                   
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax     ; move the sum into a
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     esi, eax                   ; pass a into printf
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
```

Comment: Actually doing something with the return value of this builtin really shows its purpose, for example like this : https://godbolt.org/g/VYqS9K .

Comment: I know that it's what it says, but I think that it's a little weird to say that it's "implemented in assembly", because there doesn't have to be a "true" implementation for an intrinsic. It's kind of like saying that `a / b` is implemented in assembly. There are code generation implications for true functions that are implemented in assembly that do not apply to intrinsics.

Comment: I've been proceeding on the basis that it's a reasonable assumption, and it seems to hold on the platforms I've tried.  I just couldn't find an actual statement or example to confirm it's portable.  I think the comments to the question help - it's a function (or should behave *as if*), and the inputs are passed by value.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I would be careful by calling it a function in the language sense. If so, then where it is declared? The C requires to have declaration before function can be called, otherwise it will invoke compile-time error.